# Why is my $variable acting like a string when placed in ERB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

JS:

```
$(this).attr({
    src: "<%= asset_path("\\$hoverClass"'-red.jpg') %>"
});
```

This outputs /assets/$hoverClass-red.jpg instead of /assets/sports-red.jpg ('sports' being the value of $hoverClass).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby doesn't interpolate strings like this. What you mean is this:

```
<%= asset_path("#{$hoverClass}-red.jpg") %>
```

As a note, using `$`-prefixed variables in Ruby is usually bad form since it means you're declaring them globally. This inevitably leads to name collisions, inadvertent data persistence, and a host of other problems difficult to pin down. Whenever possible use the `@`-prefixed instance variables.

You could also achieve this like:

```
$(this).attr(<%= { src: asset_path("#{$hoverClass}-red.jpg") }.to_json %>);
```

That's usually more reliable since the proper JSON escaping is done for you.

Comment: $hoverClass is a JavaScript variable inside a function.

Comment: How are you expecting JavaScript variables that execute in the browser to somehow affect the output of the Ruby code? You'll need to interpolate that in the client using JavaScript: `src.replace(/\$hoverClass/, $hoverClass)`

Comment: In cases like this you'll generally want to provide a *template* string, not a literal path. Even better, just write a JavaScript function that returns the path for you: `function asset_path(hoverClass) { return "/assets/" + hoverClass + "-red.jpg" }`

Comment: This worked. I ended up with: `$(this).attr({
  src: "/assets/" + $(this).attr('class') + "-red.jpg"
 })`

Comment: Yeah, pure JavaScript is usually the best way to go.